# Open TortoiseSVN GUI from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, svn, tortoisesvn, processbuilder

Can I launch the TortoiseSVN GUI (e.g. svn-log or preferences) from Java? I'm creating a Java program and in this program I want to open the SVN log (the GUI and not the log in the command line) of a specific svn folder.

I know I can open programs with the `ProcessBuilder` or make command line calls with the `ProcessBuilder`. But is there a way to open programs via code, which normally can only be opened in the context menu of Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Automating TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics)

In short: you call TortoiseProc.exe with needed command (and paramaters, if needed)